# mongodb Async-await Post method

Tags: javascript

how do I post to  referenced schemas in mongodb while using async-await. i was able to create the get function but i am having a hard time creating the post and the put.
 here is my get function :

Comment: and where is your genuine attempt at a post function?

Comment: none worked well, snd they all looked stupid

Answer (score 1):

I think, in your request body you should only pass issue id and user id. So when you get the task with your get task details API, mongoose will prepopulate the data.

Your request body should look like

```
{
  issue: "5ca2b1f80c2e9a13fcd5b913",
  user: "5ca2b1f80c2e9a13fcd5b90b",
  record: {
    votary: 80,
    development: 90,
    test: 100
  },
  date: "2019-03-01T15:00:00.000Z"
};
```

And then save the task details as

```
try {
  const task = new TaskModel(req.body);
  const result= await task.save()
  return api.responseJSON(res, 200, result);
} catch (e)
{
// Error
}
```

Comment: no i get an error like so for all fields * {
    "errors": {
        "date": {
            "message": "Path `date` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Path `date` is required.",

Comment: can you try sending `date` as a `ISOString` .

Comment: date is not the only problem i got same error for the usser issue and all ;(

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the code inside of post in a try/catch

```
export const post: Operation = async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    try {
        const param: any = {};
        const task = new TaskModel(req.body);
        const newTask = await task.save()
        return api.responseJSON(res, 200, newTask);
    } catch(err) {
        // treat error
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt populate referenced schema

Comment: Your document only keeps the id's of issues and users documents, it will be populated in your get function

Comment: i get this error: Tasks validation failed: date: Path `date` is required., user: Path `user` is required.

Comment: You posted your taskSchema when you should put the user schema in your question.

Comment: Show me the body on your resquest, the fields date and user are probably missing.

Comment: i added the request body

Comment: You need to insert issue and user documents before making this request, then, pass the user id on user field, and issue id on issue field. Take some time to look at mongodb documentation, this will help you.

Comment: i tried that but i couldnt make it work , if you can help me with that please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You should not save the complete `req.body` instead save only those fields which your schema accepts. And according to `Task` schema `issue` and `user` fields should store `id` but not the complete object which is there in `req.body`. Please try this and update your post method accordingly:

```
    export const post: Operation = async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
        try {
            let param: any = {};
            const user = {
                id: req.body.user.id
            };
            const issue = {
                id: req.body.issue.id
            };
            param = req.body;
            param.user = user.id
            param.issue = issue.id
            const task = new TaskModel(param);
            const newTask = await task.save()
            return api.responseJSON(res, 200, newTask);
        } catch (e) {
            api.responseJSON(res, 400, e)
        }
    };
```

Comment: posts empty object

Comment: Is it saving into database ?

Comment: doesnt save to the database and the response body is {}

Comment: i just changed type of param from const to let, can you give a try now please

Comment: i already changed that in my code but thats not the problem :+(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191198/discussion-between-vikash-singh-and-salma-zaghloul).